# Can facebook API do this?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

On my site I want members to be able to click a link `import your Facebook photo` then a Facebook popup opens and asks user to confirm that he/she wants to share their profile picture with my website.

Can this be done? What are the steps? I am looking at the Facebook graph API but I am unsure if this is the right thing, I have **huge** problems understanding their samples and "help" files.

I was able to easily do this with Gmail and Yahoo, uses can get a browser popup from them in order to confirm sharing contacts with my website, I assumed Facebook works the same to import the profile picture but I am spinning in circles.

Comment: There is an example.php in their PHP sdk, looks messy to me, it fetches sample data from a user "/naitik" but they couldn't write this in a $variable, instead you bounce around html/php areas finding locations where to edit this username in order to test on another account name.

Answer (score 1):

Within Facebook Terms for users it states that your name and picture are publicly available so one does not need permission to request it.

https://www.facebook.com/about/privacy/your-info

The `naitik` call is an example of data that is publicly available without asking for permission.

When you are requesting the current user, that is, you don't know the id or name beforehand, then you use a basic login flow which will then present one of the following dialogs.

[image: Login Dialogs]

Comment: Thanks. This is the functionality I am looking for, and how is this process started at my end? Do I start by getting an AccessToken sending a "GET" command to this URL? `/oauth/access_token?client_id={app-id}&client_secret={app-secret}&grant_type=client_credentials` Or is there a simpler way? I don't want to complicate things if it's not needed.

Comment: @adrianTNT no, that's to get an application access token. The PHP SDK follows this flow https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web-no-jssdk/